# Go, is this everything you need to know for assignments and initialization?

Tags: go

It is just mind boggling how many different ways Go has for variable initialization. May be either i don't understand this completely or Go is a big after thought. Lot of things don't feel natural and looks like they added features as they found them missing. Initialization is one of them.

[Here is running app on Go playground showing different ways of initialization](http://play.golang.org/p/B3HlJ6rOOg)

Here is what i understand

1. There are values and pointers. Values are initiated using `var =` or `:=`.
2. `:=` only works inside the methods
3. To Create value and reference you use new or `&`. And they only work on composite types.
4. There are whole new ways of creating maps and slices
5. Create slice and maps using either *make* or *var x []int*. Noticing there is no `=` or `:=`

Are there any easy way to understand all this for newbies? Reading specs gives all this in bits and pieces everywhere.

Answer (score 12):

First, to mention some incorrect statements:

> To Create value and reference you use new or &. And they only work on composite types.

new() works on everything. & doesn't

> Create slice and maps using either make or var x []int. Noticing there is no = or :=

You can actually use `:=` with `x := []int{}` or even `x := []int(nil)`. However, the first is only used when you want to make a slice of len 0 that is not nil and the second is never used because `var x []int` is nicer.

---

Lets start from the beginning. You initialize variables with `var name T`. Type inference was added because you can type less and avoid worrying about the name of a type a function returns. So you are able to do `var name = f()`.

If you want to allocate a pointer, you would need to first create the variable being pointed to and then get its pointer:

```
var x int
var px = &x
```

Requiring two statements can be bothersome so they introduced a built-in function called new(). This allows you to do it in one statement: `var px = new(int)`

However, this method of making new pointers still has an issue. What if you are building a massive literal that has structs that expect pointers? This is a very common thing to do. So they added a way (only for composite literals) to handle this.

```
var x = []*T{
    &T{x: 1},
    &T{x: 2},
}
```

In this case, we want to assign different values to fields of the struct the pointers reference. Handling this with new() would be awful so it is allowed.

---

Whenever a variable is initialized, it is always initialized to its zero value. There are no constructors. This is a problem for some of the builtin types. Specifically slices, maps, and channels. These are complicated structures. They require parameters and initialization beyond memory being set to zero. Users of Go who need to do this simply write initialization functions. So, that is what they did, they wrote `make()`. `neW([]x)` returns a pointer to a slice of x while `make([]x, 5)` returns a slice of x backed by an array of length 5. New returns a pointer while make returns a value. This is an important distinction which is why it is separate.

---

What about `:=`? That is a big clusterfuck. They did that to save on typing, but it led to some odd behaviors and the tacked on different rules until it became somewhat usable.

At first, it was a short form of var x = y. However, it was used very very often with multiple returns. And most of those multiple returns were errors. So we very often had:

```
x, err := f()
```

But multiple errors show up in your standard function so people started naming things like:

```
x, err1 := f()
y, err2 := g()
```

This was ridiculous so they made the rule that `:=` only re-declares if it is not already declared in that scope. But that defeats the point of `:=` so they also tacked on the rule that at least one must be newly declared.

Interestingly enough, this solves 95% of its problems and made it usable. Although the biggest problem I run into with it is that all the variables on the lefthand side must be identifiers. In other words, the following would be invalid because `x.y` is not an identifier:

```
x.y, z := f()
```

This is a leftover of its relation to var which can't declare anything other than an identifier.

As for why := doesn't work outside a function's scope? That was done to make writing the compiler easier. Outside a function, every part starts with a keyword (var, func, package, import). `:=` would mean that declaration would be the only one that doesn't start with a keyword.

---

So, that is my little rant on the subject. The bottom line is that different forms of declaration are useful in different areas.

Comment: +1 for pointing out several of the incorrect statements in the question

Comment: Nice history lesson about `:=`--had no idea.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this was one of those things that I found confusing early as well. I've come up with my own rules of thumb which may or may not be best practices, but they've served me well. *Tweaked after comment from Stephen about zero values*

1. Use `:=` as much as possible, let Go infer types
2. If you just need an empty slice or map (and don't need to set an initial capacity), use `{}` syntax

   `s := []string{}`
    `m := map[string]string{}`
3. The only reason to use `var` is to initialize something to a zero value (pointed out by Stephen in comments) (and yeah, outside of functions you'll need `var` or `const` as well):

   `var ptr *MyStruct // this initializes a nil pointer`
   `var t time.Time   // this initializes a zero-valued time.Time`

Comment: It is common to do `var x T` when x is being set to the zero value. You would never see `var ptr *MyStruct = nil` in real code but instead `var ptr *MyStruct`

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion is coming from mixing up the type system with declaration and initialization.

In Go, variables can be declared in two ways: using `var`, or using `:=`. `var` only *declares* the variable, while `:=` also assigns an initial value to it. For example:

```
var i int
i = 1
```

is equivalent to

```
i := 1
```

The reason this is possible is that `:=` simply assumes that the type of `i` is the same as the type of the expression it's being initialized to. So, since the expression `1` has type `int`, Go knows that `i` is being declared as an integer.

Note that you can also explicitly declare and initialize a variable with the `var` keyword as well:

```
var i int = 1
```

Those are the only two delcaration/initialization constructs in Go. You're right that using `:=` in the global scope is not allowed. Other than that, the two are interchangable, as long as Go is able to guess what type you're using on the right-hand-side of the `:=` (which is most of the time).

---

These constructs work with any types. The type system is completely independent from the declaration/initialization syntax. What I mean by that is that there are no special rules about which types you can use with the declaration/initialization syntax - if it's a type, you can use it.

With that in mind, let's walk through your example and explain everything.

**Example 1**

```
// Value Type assignments [string, bool, numbers]
// = & := Assignment
// Won't work on pointers?
var value = "Str1"
value2 := "Str2"
```

This will work with pointers. The key is that you have to be setting these equal to expressions whose types are pointers. Here are some expressions with pointer types:

- Any call to `new()` (for example, `new(int)` has type `*int`)
- Referencing an existing value (if `i` has type `int`, then `&i` has type `*int`)

So, to make your example work with pointers:

```
tmp := "Str1"
var value = &tmp // value has type *int
value2 := new(string)
*value2 = "Str2"
```

**Example 2**

```
// struct assignments
var ref1 = refType{"AGoodName"}
ref2 := refType{"AGoodName2"}
ref3 := &refType{"AGoodName2"}
ref4 := new(refType)
```

The syntax that you use here, `refType{"AGoodName"}`, is used to create and initialize a struct in a single expression. The type of this expression is `refType`.

Note that there is one funky thing here. Normally, you can't take the address of a literal value (for example, `&3` is illegal in Go). However, you *can* take the address of a literal *struct* value, like you do above with `ref3 := &refType{"AGoodName2"}`. This seems pretty confusing (and certainly confused me at first). The reason it's allowed is that it's actually just a short-hand syntax for calling `ref3 := new(refType)` and then initializing it by doing `*ref3 = refType{"AGoodName2"}`.

**Example 3**

```
// arrays, totally new way of assignment now, = or := now won't work now
var array1 [5]int
```

This syntax is actually equivalent to `var i int`, except that instead of the type being `int`, the type is `[5]int` (an array of five ints). If we wanted to, we could now set each of the values in the array separately:

```
var array1 [5]int
array1[0] = 0
array1[1] = 1
array1[2] = 2
array1[3] = 3
array1[4] = 4
```

However, this is pretty tedious. Just like with integers and strings and so on, arrays can have literal values. For example, `1` is a literal value with the type `int`. The way you create a literal array value in Go is by naming the type explicitly, and then giving the values in brackets (similar to a struct literal) like this:

```
[5]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

This is a literal value just like any other, so we can use it as an initializer just the same:

```
var array1 [5]int = [5]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
var array2 = [5]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
array3 := [5]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

**Example 4**

```
// slices, some more ways
var slice1 []int
```

Slices are very similar to arrays in how they are initialized. The only difference is that they aren't fixed at a particular length, so you don't have to give a length parameter when you name the type. Thus, `[]int{1, 2, 3}` is a slice of integers whose length is initially 3 (although could be changed later). So, just like above, we can do:

```
var slice1 []int = []int{1, 2, 3}
var slice2 = []int{1, 2, 3}
slice3 := []int{1, 2, 3}
```

**Example 5**

```
var slice2 = new([]int)
slice3 := new([]int)
```

Reasoning about types can get tricky when the types get complex. As I mentioned above, `new(T)` returns a pointer, which has type `*T`. This is pretty straightforward when the type is an int (ie, `new(int)` has type `*int`). However, it can get confusing when the type itself is also complex, like a slice type. In your example, `slice2` and `slice3` both have type `*[]int`. For example:

```
slice3 := new([]int)
*slice3 = []int{1, 2, 3}
fmt.Println((*slice3)[0]) // Prints 1
```

You may be confusing `new` with `make`. `make` is for types that need some sort of initialization. For slices, `make` creates a slice of the given size. For example, `make([]int, 5)` creates a slice of integers of length 5. `make(T)` has type `T`, while `new(T)` has type `*T`. This can certainly get confusing. Here are some examples to help sort it out:

```
a := make([]int, 5) // s is now a slice of 5 integers
b := new([]int)     // b points to a slice, but it's not initialized yet
*b = make([]int, 3) // now b points to a slice of 5 integers
```

**Example 6**

```
// maps
var map1 map[int]string
var map2 = new(map[int]string)
```

Maps, just like slices, need some initialization to work properly. That's why neither `map1` nor `map2` in the above example are quite ready to be used. You need to use `make` first:

```
var map1 map[int]string        // Not ready to be used
map1 = make(map[int]string)    // Now it can be used
var map2 = new(map[int]string) // Has type *map[int]string; not ready to be used
*map2 = make(map[int]string)   // Now *map2 can be used
```

---

**Extra Notes**

There wasn't a really good place to put this above, so I'll just stick it here.

One thing to note in Go is that if you declare a variable without initializing it, it isn't actually uninitialized. Instead, it has a "zero value." This is distinct from C, where uninitialized variables can contain junk data.

Each type has a zero value. The zero values of most types are pretty reasonable. For example, the basic types:

- `int` has zero value `0`
- `bool` has zero value `false`
- `string` has zero value `""`

(other numeric values like `int8`, `uint16`, `float32`, etc, all have zero values of `0` or `0.0`)

For composite types like structs and arrays, the zero values are recursive. That is, the zero value of an array is an array with all of its entries set to their respective zero values (ie, the zero value of `[3]int` is `[3]int{0, 0, 0}` since `0` is the zero value of `int`).

---

Another thing to watch out for is that when using the `:=` syntax, certain expressions' types cannot be inferred. The main one to watch out for is `nil`. So, `i := nil` will produce a compiler error. The reason for this is that `nil` is used for all of the pointer types (and a few other types as well), so there's no way for the compiler to know if you mean a nil int pointer, or a nil bool pointer, etc.